# Why is this SQL query wrong?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
CD.CountryID, CD.GrossLimit, CD.UnsecuredLimit,
SUM(LT1.Amount), SUM(LT1.Unsecured), 
    (100*SUM(LT1.Unsecured) / CD.UnsecuredLimit) as PercOverCountryLimit
FROM CountryDetail CD 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT CompanyName AS Company, CollateralSName as Collateral, SUM(Amount) AS Amount,  
       SUM(Usecured) AS Unsecured, LT.Date as Date, Max(CountryID) as CountryID
    FROM Loanstotal LT
    WHERE YearMonth = @YearMonth
    GROUP BY CompanyName, CollateralSName, LT.Date
) LT1
GROUP BY CountryID, GrossLimit, UnsecuredLimit
ON CD.CountryID = LT1.CountryID
```

Comment: how do you mean wrong? Returns incorrect results, errors out?

Comment: I don't like the formatting, but I doubt that is what you mean.  Could you describe what you mean by "wrong"?  Please do so by editing the question and including information about what you expect this query to do.

Comment: I suspect it errors out on the `GROUP BY/ON` construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I see some  possible problems right off
First your group by is in the incorrect place, it needs to be after the ON clause in the join not before it.

Possible issue with a typo: SUM(Usecured) should that be SUM(Unsecured)?

Next depending on what type of data is in the fields you are summing up, you may have a problem with integer math. An integer divided by an integer will give an integer result (3/2 = 1 for example) so you must convert one value to a numeric.

Other issues may be there depending on which version of SQL you are using, You need to specify which database backed to get the best answers. Mine are based on what SQL server would want.

Comment: Thanks HLGEM, The placing of the Group by clause may be the problem. The name of the field is Usecured although it really means Unsecured, the division is between Real type. Using SQL server 2008 with c# VS10.

Comment: +1 since the requester didn't give you a +1, but marked you as an answer. ;)